# Character encoding issues - UTF-8 / Issue while transmitting data on the internet?

Tags: php, drupal, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got data being sent from a client side which is sending it like this:

```
// $booktitle = "Comí habitación bailé"

$xml_obj = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

// node created with booktitle and added to xml_obj 
// NO htmlentities / other transformations done

$returnHeader = drupal_http_request($url, $headers = array("Content-Type:  text/xml; charset=utf-8"), $method = 'POST', $data = $xml_data, $retry = 3);
```

When I receive it at my end (via that drupal_http_request) and I do htmlentities on it, I get the following:

```
 Com&Atilde;&shy; habitaci&Atilde;&sup3;n bail&Atilde;&copy;
```

Which when displayed looks like gibberish:

```
 ComÃ­ HabitaciÃ³n BailÃ©
```

What is going wrong?

---

Edit 1)

```
<?php
$title = "Comí habitación bailé";
echo "title=$title\n";
echo 'encoding is '.mb_detect_encoding($title);
$heutf8 = htmlentities($title, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
echo "heutf8=$heutf8\n";
?>
```

Running this test script on a Windows machine and redirecting to a file shows:

```
title=Comí habitación bailé
encoding is UTF-8heutf8=
```

Running this on a linux system:

```
title=Comí habitación bailé
encoding is UTF-8PHP Warning:  htmlentities(): Invalid multibyte sequence in argument in /home/testaccount/public_html/test2.php on line 5
heutf8=
```

Comment: It seems you get ISO-8859 instead of UTF8..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`htmlentities` interprets its input as ISO-8859-1 by default; are you passing UTF-8 for the charset parameter?

Comment: @AlanBeats: Your problem there is that `$title` contains non-UTF-8 characters (your source file is probably ISO-8859-1). Unfortunately, `mb_detect_encoding` seems to screw it up unless you pass true for its 'strict' parameter, reporting "UTF-8" even though the string is not in fact UTF-8.

Comment: with regard to your original point about htmlentities, please see Edit 1 - Am I not doing the correct thing there?

Comment: @AlanBeats: You are doing the correct thing there, except for the part where the data in `$title` isn't UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem...!

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't encode the entities with htmlentities just for outputting it correctly (you should as stated in the comments use htmlspecialchars to avoid cross side scripting) , just set the correct headers and meta end echo the values normally:

```
<?php
 header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, however in this case, the drupal_http_request() call is making an API request to my code. My code saves it as indicated into the MySQL database... so we havent reached the displaying stage yet actually...

Comment: The table here in MySQL is of type - 'latin1_swedish_ci' (is taht the cause of the problem?)

Comment: Bad idea, unless you like [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerabilities in your website. At least use `htmlspecialchars` when echoing untrusted data.

Comment: @Anomie - you're mentioning bad idea for what exactly?

Comment: @AlanBeats: Consider what happens if the user enters something like `<script>alert('Pwned!')</script>`, and you echo that to the page without escaping `<` and `>`. Of course, in the real world they'd probably do something worse than just alerting "Pwned!".

Comment: I didn't say you didn't have to sanitize the output i just said that you didn't need htmlentities for displaying 'à' correctly in UTF-8 that's all.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: You said "you shouldn't encode the entities" and "echo the values normally". Maybe you knew what you meant, but others won't.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: Also, BTW, please read [replying in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#link-comment-reply). Thanks.

Comment: @Anomie yes sorry, i didn't specify the name, i corrected the answer with your correction on the fact that you should encode your output for cross site scripting, it's always better to specify it.

Comment: Hi Nicola - thanks for your advice - i will incorporate that into the code!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing headers information in a key/value array format.

Something like

`$headers = array("Content-Type" =>  "text/xml; charset=utf-8"")`

Comment: doing exactly that at the client end - $headers = array("Content-Type:  text/xml; charset=utf-8")

Comment: yours `$headers` var is differente from mine.